# Launching Word x64 in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ms-office

I am currently working on very old project, which is based on Delphi 5. When I am trying to open new Word document on x64 system, I recive this error:

[image: Error]

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251410.aspx), the source of problem might be the version of my Office (x64). In application we use TWordApplication object to manage Word invoking. Is there any solution for that problem? On Office x86 everything works fine.

This is part of the code:

```
Word := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
Word.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
Word.AutoQuit := True;
Word.Connect;
Word.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType := False;
Word.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType := False;
Word.Options.SuggestSpellingCorrections := False;
Word.Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling := False;
Word.Options.ShowReadabilityStatistics := False;
Word.Options.IgnoreInternetAndFileAddresses := False;
Word.Options.IgnoreUppercase   := True;
Word.Options.IgnoreMixedDigits := True;
Word.Options.ReplaceSelection  := True;
```

Comment: Does Microsoft let you install both x86 and x64 versions of Office?

Comment: @marcus no that is not possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the VBA code attached to your document rather than the Delphi code. Specifically a hidden module named API is implicated. Perhaps this is in a template or an add-in or an auto start.

Hidden modules are protected which suggests that you may not be able to modify the module. You could try contacting the author of the protected module or perhaps removing whatever it is that introduced this module.

Reverting to 32 bit Office is an easier solution. This will require you to uninstall 64 bit Office first since the two editions do not co-exist.

Comment: Maybe it is an easier solution, but I cannot be sure, that all of clients uses Ofiice in x86 version :-)

Comment: In that case you need to work out what this API module is, where it comes from, and how to deal with it.

Comment: @user987903: it isn't that hard :) One piece of advice: learn about `option explicit` and use it! It'll save you a lot of hassle because without it any misspelled variable name introduces a new variable...